# What is the best practice to work with LayoutBuilder in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have built an application for mobile screens and I now want to add Desktop and Tablet screens to it.
After a bit of googling I read about the `LayoutBuilder` and my question is:

What is the best Code/Project Structure to use `LayoutBuilder`?

Can I use it with the [folder-by-feature pattern](https://pub.dev/packages/feature_folder_cli)?

Should I use a Global Builder or add one into each feature?

Answer (score 0):

You need to separately defines the mobile body and tablet body if layout changes dynamically. see the screen shot [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ng5B.png)